# Using a regex to match a substring in a Laravel route

Tags: php, regex, laravel, routes

My URL is: www.foo.com/some-bar-slug-here/page

I can't get a route to catch if the string "bar" is found in the slug shown above:

```
Route::any('{myslug}/page/', array('as'=>'bar-page', 'uses'=>'Controllers\MyBar@index'))
     ->where('myslug','/bar/');
```

If I use the regex expression `[0-9A-Za-z\-]+` it works, but it doesn't work for `/bar/`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it working with `^([0-9A-Za-z\-]+)?bar([0-9A-Za-z\-]+)?`

So the updated route code looks like this:

```
Route::any('{myslug}/page/', array('as'=>'bar-page', 'uses'=>'Controllers\MyBar@index'))
 ->where('myslug','^([0-9A-Za-z\-]+)?bar([0-9A-Za-z\-]+)?');
```

Bonus: To make it case insensitive, I do this: `^([0-9A-Za-z\-]+)?(?i)bar([0-9A-Za-z\-]+)?`

Note: If you are using a copy of this route further down in the your routes file, but searching for a different sub-string then you will need to name your `{myslug}` to something different like `{myslug2}`, otherwise Laravel will not run all of the routes.

Comment: did you refer to a resource on why we don't use standart regEx?