# Laravel regex route

Tags: php, regex, laravel-5

I would like to call one function from a controller to all route begin with my_website/doc/.

But I can't find something that to do that in laravel 5.

something like: `Route::get('my_website/doc/*', 'WelcomeController@doc');`

for exemple:

```
my_website/doc/test --> WelcomeController@doc

my_website/doc/test/1 --> WelcomeController@doc

my_website/doc/test/1/etc --> WelcomeController@doc
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regex to match a substring in a Laravel route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198019/using-a-regex-to-match-a-substring-in-a-laravel-route)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
Route::get('my_website/docs/{page?}', 'WelcomeController@doc');
```

`{page?}` will be

- `test` for **my_website/doc/test**
- `test/1` for **my_website/doc/test/1**
- `test/1/etc` for **my_website/doc/test/1/etc**

At `doc` method

```
public function doc($page = null)
{
    dd($page);
}
```

Comment: Nope. As soon as it hits the `/`, it'll throw a 404. You need to append `->where()` to your route definition.

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach to solve the problem:

```
Route::get('{slug}', function($slug){
    dd($slug);
    //
})->where('slug', 'my_website/docs.*');
```